# Spring Boot: application-{profile}.yml not loaded when located in subdirectory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am working on a **Spring Boot** (2.3.10) Application and 3 profiles are defined using **YAML**, e.g. prof1, prof2, prof3.

The file `application.yml` is located in `src/main/resources`. When the individual files for each profile, i.e. `appication-{profile}.yml` are placed in the same directory, or inside the `config/` folder, everything works fine. I am able to activate a profile and override the profile-specific properties.

***The problem***

I would like to place each `.yml` file in a separate directory, either under `/config` or not. For example:

- resources

  - config

    - prof1

      - application-prof1.yml

or

- resources

  - prof2

    - application-prof2.yml

Hoever, in both cases of the example above, the file does not seem to be loaded and the properties have the defualt values.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Specify those directories as `spring.config.additional-locations` else those won't be taken into account (as explained in the documentation).

Comment: @M.Deinum, it is actually `spring.config.additional-location` without the `s`. Other than that your comment nails it ;)

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your comment. I have tried specifying the directories using `spring.config.additional-location` but with no luck. I have a tried:
`classpath:/config/prof1/` and `file:./config/prof1/application-prof1.yml`

Comment: That should be an environment variable or passed to the application while started. How did you set that property?

Comment: @M.Deinum I used  `-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments` to set it and it works now. Previously I was using `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments`. Thank you!!